# TeamViewer 12 contact list operating with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, teamviewer, contacts, focus

In previous versions of TV there was an ability to operate contact list with keyboard. But in new version (12) I can't move focus to contact list, because button with my account (in bottom-right corner of TV window) absent in tab-transition list, and even if additional window with contact list is shown, I can't move focus to it, because this window absent in system window list.
And new TV interface brings no solution too, it makes situation worse: I can't even access menu or any other element on the left pane, because they are absent in tab-transition list.

Is there special keystrokes or tricks (no mouse or mouse emulation!) for moving focus to these elements, or for enabling them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! Just found the answer! But for the old interface only on the moment, so, if anybody suggests the solution for the new interface — it will be very good.

For accessing contacts it needs to move focus to button with account name and activate it (by `Space Bar` or `Enter`). For this operation that button must be in a tab-transition list. On the first tab, Remote Control, the button absent in that list, but for the second tab, Meeting, the button present in tab-transition list. So, we need Meeting tab to be active. If not, than we should make a trick: use `F10` for moving focus to menu, then use `Esc` for cancelling drop-down menu, then move focus to list of the tabs (Remote Control and Meeting) by single `Tab`, then use `Right` to switch to the Meeting tab. After it, we may just move focus two position backwards by using `Shift+Tab` twice for selecting the button.

So, conclusion: sequence below works in any situation.
activate TV window (if not already), `F10`, `Esc`, `Tab`, `Right`, `Shift+Tab` twice, `Space bar` or `Enter` (if contacts' window was already opened, then repeat last key)